# How can I increment and decrement a counter for the amount of cards in a deck with a certain card name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day;

I'm continuing my attempt to create a deck building application for Cardfight!! Vanguard

There is a rule you can't have more than 4 of the same card in a deck, and no more than 50 cards in a deck.

I'm trying to make it so that I have a counter that increases when a card is added to a deck and decreases when a card is taken out of the deck. But this counter must be for each individual card which starts off at 0 and increases by 1 every time a card with a specific name is added to the deck.

I have a vanguard object and database array where I can create new Vanguard objects easily. I have a variable within the Vanguard object (`this.cardLimit = 0`) which will set the card limit initially to 0 for each new card.

Then when a new card `[addToDeck]` is added to the deck, it will increment a counter for that specific card within the database: `database[addToDeck].cardLimit++`, until the maximum of 4 is reached, after which point this if statement will not work:

```
if (deck.length < 51 && database[addToDeck].cardLimit < 5)
```

My problem is - as you will see in the code below - I can't figure out a way to decrement this value when I remove a card using jquery. What I do is dynamically add card names to a div, and when a card name in that div is clicked on, it will remove not only the card from the div but the card from the deck array as well by splicing.

I can't just do `database[addToDeck].cardLimit--` as you will see in my code because I use jQuery and "this" to specifically refer to the part of the `div` being clicked on.

My question is then.... how can I decrease the counter based on the specifications of the code I have provided so far? When my Jquery (last jQuery instance in the code) for removing the part of the deck runs, I need to decrease the counter for the specific card that was removed.

Let me know if you need any further clarification... It's not easy for me to explain my problem in simple terms. Thanks so much for reading.

JavaScript / Jquery:

```
function Vanguard(name,grade,skill,power,shield,critical, type, trigger, nation, clan, race, flavor, effect, imageURL){
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
    this.skill = skill;
    this.power = power;
    this.shield = shield;
    this.critical = critical;
    this.type = type;
    this.trigger = trigger;
    this.nation = nation;
    this.clan = clan;
    this.race = race;
    this.flavor = flavor;
    this.effect = effect;
    this.imageURL = imageURL;
    this.cardLimit = 0;
};

var database = {};
database['asura kaiser'] = new Vanguard("Asura Kaiser", 3, "Twin Drive!!", 11000, "", 1, "Normal Unit", "None", "Star Gate", "Nova Grappler", "Battleroid", "The death blow! Kaiser Buster!", "<br/>[CONT](VC/RC):If you do not have another «Nova Grappler» vanguard or rear-guard, this unit gets [Power] -2000. <br/> [AUTO](VC):When this unit's drive check reveals a grade 3 «Nova Grappler», choose one of your rear-guards, and [Stand] it.", "http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120428001646/cardfight/images/thumb/a/a6/VGE_BT01-008EN.jpg/300px-VGE_BT01-008EN.jpg");
database['king of knights, alfred'] = new Vanguard("King of Knights, Alfred", 3, "Twin Drive!!", 10000, "", 1, "Normal Unit", "None", "United Sanctuary", "Royal Paladin", "Human", "I command you under the name of the King of Knights! Warriors, heed my call!", "<br/>[CONT](VC):Your units cannot boost this unit. <br/> [CONT](VC):During your turn, this unit gets [Power]+2000 for each of your «Royal Paladin» rear-guards. <br/> [ACT](VC/RC):[Counter Blast (3)] Search your deck for up to one grade 2 or less «Royal Paladin», call it to (RC), and shuffle your deck.", "http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121009013434/cardfight/images/thumb/9/95/BT01-001EN_RRR.jpg/300px-BT01-001EN_RRR.jpg");
database['dragonic overlord'] = new Vanguard("Dragonic Overlord", 3, "Twin Drive!!", 11000, "", 1, "Normal Unit", "None", "Dragon Sanctuary", "Kagerou", "Dragon", "<br/>(TD02):Reduce all to ashes, flame of the apocalypse! Eternal Flame! <br/> (BT01):Burn, flame of despair! Eternal Flame!", "<br/>[CONT](VC/RC):If you do not have another «Kagero» vanguard or rear-guard, this unit gets [Power]-2000. <br/> [ACT](VC/RC):[Counter Blast (3)] Until end of turn, this unit gets [Power]+5000, gets '[AUTO](VC/RC):When this unit's attack hits an opponent's rear-guard, [Stand] this unit', and loses 'Twin Drive!!'.", "http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120131161306/cardfight/images/thumb/3/33/TD02-001EN.jpg/300px-TD02-001EN.jpg");
database['ceo amaterasu'] = new Vanguard("CEO Amaterasu", 3, "Twin Drive", 10000, "", 1, "Normal Unit", "None", "United Sanctuary", "Oracle Think Tank", "Human", "<br/>(BT01):Shape my desire. Project it before me, Yata no Kagami! <br/>(EB05):Feel the flow of time. You will create the future.", "<br/>[CONT](VC):During your turn, if the number of cards in your hand is four or greater, this unit gets [Power] +4000. <br/> [AUTO](VC):At the beginning of your main phase, Soul Charge (1), look at the top card of your deck, and put that card on the top or the bottom of your deck. <br/> [AUTO](VC/RC):[Soul Blast (8) & Counter Blast (5)] When this unit's attack hits, you may pay the cost. If you do, draw up to five cards.)", "http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120831173054/cardfight/images/thumb/3/30/BT01-S05EN_SP.jpg/300px-BT01-S05EN_SP.jpg");
database['alfred early'] = new Vanguard("Alfred Early", 3, "Twin Drive!!", 10000, "", 1, "Normal Unit", "None", "United Sanctuary", "Royal Paladin", "Human", "To preserve the smiles of his people, the young King leads knights to battle.", "AUTO: When this unit is placed on Vanguard Circle, choose up to one card named 'Blaster Blade' from your soul, and call it to Rear-guard Circle.", "http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120926194218/cardfight/images/thumb/5/5e/PR-0005EN.jpg/300px-PR-0005EN.jpg");

function printVanguard(p, name){
      for (var p in database[name]){
       if (p !== 'imageURL'){
         document.getElementById('output').innerHTML +=('<b>' + p.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + p.slice(1) + '</b>: ' + database[name][p] + '<br />');
      }}
};

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#button').click(function(){
   $('#output').html(""); //clear old search
   $('#image').html(""); // clear old image
    var userInput = $('input[name=searchItem]').val();
    userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
     $('#output').append(printVanguard(userInput, userInput));
   var image = $('<img>').attr('src', database[userInput].imageURL);
   $('#image').append(image);
 });
 var deck = [];

 $('#add').click(function(){
     var addToDeck = $('input[name=searchItem]').val();
     addToDeck = addToDeck.toLowerCase();
     database[addToDeck].cardLimit++;
     if (deck.length < 51 && database[addToDeck].cardLimit < 5){
      deck.push(addToDeck);
      $('#quantity').html("");
      $('#save').prepend('<div id="quantity">' + 'Total: ' + deck.length + '</div>');   
      $('#save').append('<div id="cardList">' + database[deck[deck.length-1]].name + '</div>');
      }
 });
  $(document).on('click','[id^=cardList]', function(){
   $(this).remove();
     deck.splice(deck[this], 1);
    $('#quantity').html("");
     $('#save').prepend('<div id="quantity">' + 'Total: ' + deck.length + '</div>');
  });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script type = "text/javascript" src='script.js'>
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <form name="searchForm">
         <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter Card Name" name="searchItem"/>
     </form>
     <div id="button">Search!</div>
     <div id="add">Add to Deck</div>
    <br/>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <div id="image"></div>
    <div id="save"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/8QR7q
Provided by Malik

Test Inputs:  "Alfred Early", "CEO Amaterasu", "Dragonic Overlord", "Asura Kaiser", or "King of Knights, Alfred"

Comment: This question would be a lot easier to understand if you stripped it down to a basic example demonstrating the principle you are confused with.

Comment: Stripping it down may also help you see what the problem is in the first place, and you may find your solution in doing so.

Comment: If I enter "Asura Kaiser" 4 times as input. This will make database[asura kaiser].cardLimit++ run 4 times so that it equals 4. This means the if statement will no longer run and you cant add more cards to the deck. Now if I click on "Asura Kaiser" from the cardList div and make it so that there are only 3 in the div, the counter will still be at 4. Then, you can't add any more cards of the same name to the deck even though there are only three in the div because the counter for this card name wasn't decreased.

Comment: That's why my title specifically mentions counters. I know what the problem is, but not how to fix it, so I am posting here for any insight.

Comment: `deck` is an array, so `deck[this]` isn't going to find anything, or even `deck[this.innerText.toLowerCase()]` (what I tried before realizing it was an array, and not an object). You're going to have to manually search your `deck` array for an occurrence of the card you want to remove, or change `deck`'s type.

Comment: So I'm not actually removing any cards from my deck, just from the div? Do you think deck would be better off as an object?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a fiddle to test it.

Comment: @Jehanzeb.Malik Although most SO users are probably familiar with what a fiddle is, without a link it could be quite confusing to someone who isn't! http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I dont know what fiddle is but here is my codecademy project on it so far: http://www.codecademy.com/users/50eee296a384f9b667007208/projects/500c7558d143430002002551/

You can enter "Asura Kaiser", "Alfred Early", "Ceo Amaterasu", "Dragonic Overlord", or "King of Knights - Alfred" in any case without the quotes but including the full name.

If you click on "add to deck" 4 times after typing in the card name, clicking on the green output div and removing one card name, and trying to add another card name, it wont work.

Comment: I made a fiddle but not sure it works... I would refer to my codecademy to see my code
http://jsfiddle.net/NcpQK/

Comment: You needed to include jquery from panel in left. Here I created a fiddle for anyone else who is testing. http://jsfiddle.net/8QR7q/

Comment: Thanks Malik. I will keep that in mind for next time... 

For anyone testing you can use these inputs: "Alfred Early", "CEO Amaterasu", "Dragonic Overlord", "Asura Kaiser", or "King of Knights, Alfred"

Comment: It might be helpful to re-think the architecture of this whole thing.  It seems like a `Vanguard` object really just represents an individual card. If this is the case, then card contains a dynamic `cardLimit` property.  This is sort of weird, because each individual card's cardLimit should be static and equal to 4.  Maybe consider normalizing this a little bit and create a separate object to represent a player's deck - just my two cents.